# proof checking machine vs. provability checking machine

Tags: logic, algorithms, set-theory, proof-theory

Let M be a proof-checking Turing machine which takes two inputs, A and B. :

M(A,B) = 0 if A codes a valid proof of the sentence coded by B in ZFC.

M(A,B) = 1 if A does not code a valid proof of the sentence coded by B in ZFC.

.

Let M' be a provability-checking Turing machine which takes input B. :

M'(B) = 0 if B is provable in ZFC.

M'(B) does not terminate   if B is not provable in ZFC.

.

My question:
If M(X,B) = 0    then, M'(X) = 0 always?

It means, a valid proof is always provable?

Comment: By the definition of formal proof, yes. One can assume that (among other things) the "machine" $M'$, which for many theories cannot be a Turing machine, generates all sequences that are formal proofs, and verifies for each squence whether our sentence is the last entry in the proof.

Comment: I edited that it is on ZFC. Now, the M' can be Turing machine?

Comment: On the understanding that on many inputs (refutable sentences, and more) $M'$ does not terminate, sure, since ZFC is recurisvely axiomatizable.